# How to process data with large features but small samples when using DNN?

Tags: keras

In a 3-class classification problem, I have the 3-class data with 46504 features but only 144 samples (size: `144 * 46504`). I know that larger number of features usually results in overfitting, so what is a better solution for data with much larger number of features and much smaller number of samples? Thanks.

I just tried a simple DNN by `keras` and obviously the result is overfitting(training `acc` > 0.9 but evaluation `acc` is about 0.2-0.3).

```py
model = Sequential([
    Dense(256, activation='relu', input_shape=(46504,)),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(rate=0.2),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(rate=0.2),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(rate=0.2),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: what does your data look like? have you tried any dimensionality reduction techniques?

Comment: 1. My data look like :
array([[ 4.41407420e-03, -9.15633500e-03, -1.79063707e-03, ...,
        -1.40708175e-02,  2.77890721e-02,  3.90078960e- ...])
Nothing new but a 144 * 46507 matrix with float between -0.4 - 0.4 (mostly between -0.1 - 0.1)
2. I have tried to delete some unimportant features but not worked well, without any clue about this problem. Is there a general procedure to process this kind of data?